# How do I keep all of the data in a has_many :through ActiveRecord relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make my ActiveRecord queries more efficient. I have Users and Items, a user has a feeling about an item, with a boolean response.

Here's my models:

User:

```
has_many :feelings
has_many :items, :through => :feelings
```

Feeling:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item
attr_accessible :response
```

Item:

```
attr_accessible :name
```

So, I can get a list of a user's feelings by:

```
User.find(1).feelings
```

and I can get a list of the items he has feelings about by:

```
User.find(1).items
```

This is all fine. What I want though, is a combination of the two above queries in one result set. Ideally, I'd like to be able to query a list of the user's items, and with those results get their response on each item.

If this was straight SQL, I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN feelings ON items.id=feelings.item_id WHERE feelings.user_id = 1
```

This then gives me everything I need in one table. This is also what ActiveRecord does when querying `User.find(1).items`, except it throws away the data in the feelings table before it creates my hash of results.

How do I stop it throwing out the intermediatry data, and hence saving me an extra database query?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use write it like this in Rails 3,

```
User.find(1).feelings.includes(:item)
```

and in Rails 2,

```
User.find(1).feelings.find(:all, :include => :item)
```

Usually this results two queries. One selects the feelings, and another select the items.